# How can I remotely lock and erase phone data?

Tags: 8.0

How can I lock, and erase all my Windows Phone 8 device, if it was stolen or forgotten somewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a feature called **Find My Phone** which you can use it.

To enable locking and erasing the phone data remotely, you will need to have the following settings enabled. To check, go to **Settings > Find My Phone** and check the following

- Always use push notifications(not SMS) to send commands and apps to my phone
- Save my phone's location periodically and before the battery runs out to make it easier to find

**To lock your phone:**

- On your computer, go to [windowsphone.com](http://www.windowsphone.com/).
- Point to the phone in the top-right corner, then click Find My Phone. If you're prompted, sign in with the same Microsoft account you used to sign in on your phone.
- To lock your phone and show a message on the lock screen, click Lock, then follow the instructions. If you don't already have a password set up on your phone, you'll need to enter one – you'll use it to unlock the phone if you get it back.

**To Erase phone data**

- On your computer, go to [windowsphone.com](http://www.windowsphone.com/).
- Point to the phone in the top-right corner, then click Find My Phone. If you're prompted, sign in with the same Microsoft account you used to sign in on your phone.
- Click Erase.
- If you're absolutely, positively sure, tick the **I'm sure! Please erase my phone now** checkbox, then click Erase.

*[Source](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/how-to/wp8/settings-and-personalization/find-a-lost-phone)*